# Use over ssh automatically a different shell than the users default

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh

We use as the default shell: Bash on our servers but some of us like zsh more, so we searching for a way, to set ZSH automatically.

chsh to zsh i not an option.

Comment: If I may ask: *why* is `chsh` not an option?

Comment: because we use only one user.. i know it's bad but is not my descison :/

Comment: wait, you only have 1 account, but you still want different shells for different users? ...huh?

Comment: users = real people.. sorry that was not clear defined ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
ssh -t remote_user@remote_host zsh
```

?

Depends on how 'automatically' do you want it.
If you want that just `ssh -t remote_user@remote_host` should give you zsh prompt, then you should think on the lines of bash functions probably. but IMO, that would be a really bad way to do it.